# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Tags: java, spring, maven, jstl

Muy buenos dias a todos, tengo un problema con un proyecto de algunas dependencias de Spring junto con Maven, lo que pasa es que baje el proyecto de un repositorio y salieron unos errores que desconozco, los errores son:

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for
>   "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
>
> The content of element type "application" is incomplete, it must match
>   "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)".
>
> The function fn:escapeXml is undefined
>
> The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the
>   Java Build Path

[image: Esto es lo que me sale:]

Espero y me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en esto y no tenga una pizca de idea de como empezar, de antemano les mando un cordial saludo

Comment: Para quienes han votado a cierre: el contenido de la pregunta explica el problema. Si no conocen sobre la tecnología, **evitar votar a cierre**.

Answer (score 1):

El proyecto carece de las dependencias a las librerías JSTL y Java Servlet. Es probable que al generarse se haya desplegado en un servidor de aplicaciones JEE como JBoss o GlassFish que ya provee esta librería pero tú lo intentes desplegar en un contenedor de servlets como Tomcat o Jetty que no la poseen.

Solución: agrega la librería en tus dependencias o usa el servidor de aplicaciones apropiado para tu aplicación.

Aquí te brindo las dependencias para maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hola Luiggi Mendoza! Esas dependecias en donde las agrego? Y despues de eso que sigue? Y el servidor de aplicacion que estoy usando es:Pivotal tc Server Developer

Comment: En el pom de tu proyecto, en la sección `<dependencies>`

Comment: Hola de nuevo, tal parece que no funciono! Voy actualizar la la pregunta poder añadir un pantallazo.

Comment: Luego de agregar las dependencias, debes actualizar el proyecto maven en tu IDE (en este caso, Eclipse) para que tome las nuevas librerías. Con eso listo, ya deberías dejar de ver esos mensajes de error.